# Name change not reflected on edited CW answer

Tags: bug, community-wiki, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

**EDIT**: Just realized this has been [asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design), sorta... though if that question represents behavior by design, I do find it odd that CW posts with only one revision do reflect display name changes.

---

I used to use "David" as my display name on SO. Recently I changed it to "David Zaslavsky". But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/730393#730393) still shows my old display name:

[image: Wrong way to display my name]

I'm pretty sure the problem has something to do with the answer having been edited, because [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659752/programming-challenge-can-you-code-a-hello-world-program-as-a-palindrome/660212#660212) I posted to the same question shows my display name correctly:

[image: Right way to display my name]

What gives?

Comment: +1 for the brilliant unicorn. This sets a new standard.

Comment: There's a (well-hidden) way for mods to regenerate the denormalized info on CW posts which I just used, so it shows the correct name now.

Comment: The unicorn is very happy to be appreciated :-) nice to know my question has some value despite being a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, and @balpha: thanks. I didn't really mind that the name wasn't shown correctly, I just wanted to point it out in case it really was a bug.