# User that made a community wiki post isn't really anonymized

Tags: bug, deleted-accounts, anonymous

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

I looked at [Neil's old account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/anon) and [one of his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245196/c-urban-myths) still showed his full name "Neil Butterworth" as the community wiki post author.

Was this an oversight? Should this not display "anon" as well?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design