# User names incorrectly displayed on CW post if name is changed subsequently

Tags: bug, community-wiki, display-names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

It was a fairly unique set of circumstances that led me to noticing this, but it would appear that when a CW post displays a user name then it doesn't update if the user name is changed.  Here's the relevant screenshot just in case it's a browser issue.

[image: User names incorrectly shown]

Context: On TeX-SX we had a user who called him/herself "Moderator".  This [was felt to be a bit confusing](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2446/user-named-moderator) and the user was asked to change his/her name.  The user agreed, but couldn't do so straightaway and posted the above.  Later, it appears that they have managed to change their name.  But the CW post attribution doesn't reflect this.  Clicking on the edit history reveals the correct (new) name.