# Why does my name change not register on Community Wiki posts?

Tags: support, community-wiki, user-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

A few weeks ago I changed my name on SO from a pseudonym to my real name.  It has registered everywhere on SO without problem.

However, today I noticed that a [community wiki post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156351/636656) I made still lists it as "99% gsk3" e.g. my pseudonym.  Is not updating names in CW posts a deliberate convention, and if so why?

Comment: This is by-design http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47474/167443

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link.  I'm voting to close as exact duplicate.  At least this question can be a signpost, as the linked post definitely got lost in the sea of "why is my question CW?"s.