# Why is this CW post saying 36% unknown?

Tags: bug, community-wiki, attribution

Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110188/is-there-a-pdo-tutorial-for-the-beginners)

> [image]

it says "36% unknown". No user by the name of 'unknown' appears in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14110188/revisions) ([screenshot just in case some wag changes his username to 'unknown'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8FP0.png))

What madness is this? Who is this 'unknown' you speak of?

Comment: One of the users was probably known as "unknown" previously - the username attached to community wiki posts does not get updated when a user changes their name. See [Do old usernames stick to CW posts by design?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/do-old-usernames-stick-to-cw-posts-by-design)

Comment: @animuson no, I don't think so. More likely it's due to "Community" edits, in this case insert duplicate link then removing it. Probably the relevant field for user name is empty so it displays as "unknown".

Comment: @animuson: I thought of that, but it seemed unlikely that that happened within 20 hours. I've seen the OP around, he hasn't changed his username. And the other user who added 36% of the info to the page (teresko), well, looking at replies to his comments he hasn't changed his username in the past day either. There are comments from yesterday calling him "teresko", and you can only change your name once a month.

Comment: @Manishearth even i am sure he(teresko) hasnt change his name for 77days .. nor me ..for 50 days

Comment: @NullPointer - He means who?

Comment: @hims056: no, the "who" was a joke. I know that there isn't any "who", it's a bug (or Community♦)

Comment: also same on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post this post

Comment: The answer posted here is **incorrect**. I actually figured this out a while back, and edited it into the FAQ on community wiki posts, [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Comment: @Sonic since we no longer close as dupe of a faq post, can you please post a new answer, quoting relevant parts from the faq if needed?