# Can Community Wiki Posts be Deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, community-wiki

Is it possible for community wiki posts to be removed or deleted?

The link to the community post given [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161136/why-is-this-cw-post-saying-36-unknown) seems to be non-existant, although the first link to the question works fine. Browsing through the answers I could not find a community wiki post which has the same commentator as the one on the linked picture in the linked post.

Even if I consider that the answer has been so edited that I can't recognize it from the wording in the picture, should not the comments remain unchanged?

What am I missing?

Edit 1:

1. What are the reasons for which a community post can be removed?
2. Does not removing a community post defeat it's purpose?
3. Who can remove the community post?

Comment: Yeah, they can be removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the reasons for which a community post can be removed?

The same exact reasons as deleting any other post on the site. If it doesn't belong on our site, then it should be deleted. Community wiki is not any sort of "immunity" for posts.

> Does not removing a community post defeat it's purpose?

Not at all. Community wiki is just a post status that indicates it is being maintained by many members of the community and not just one person. It also lets users with lower reputation edit without needing their edits to be approved.

> Who can remove the community post?

The same people who remove any other post - any user with [10,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) or [20,000 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), depending on whether it's a question or an answer, as well as diamond moderators.