# Username not changed when question is made Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, bug, community-wiki, display-names

I was recently browsing through Meta, when I came across [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) which was made a Community wiki. When I was looking through it, I realized that the user who had asked the question, ([Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/377214/sonic-the-curiouser-hedgehog)) had changed his username from "Sonic the Masked Werehog" to "Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog" (presumably) **after** the question that they asked was made Community Wiki.

[image: Screenshot]

Is this a bug? or a feature that was left as-is like the "feature" that usernames mentioned in comments do not change after the user has changed their name?

Comment: This was previously reported at [Old usernames stick to Community Wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47474/old-usernames-stick-to-community-wiki-posts), which was marked as "by design" with the reason that the name is *stored in a denormalized field, so it will reflect the username at the time it was last calculated (usually on edit).*