# New editor sees quoted images as spoilers, deletes markdown

Tags: bug, design, markdown, editor, spoilers

In an [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323637/323179), I have some images with the syntax

```
>![][1]

[1]: example.com
```

The new editor (when not in markdown mode) wants to interpret this as an empty link in a spoiler:

[image: reveal spoiler]

Switching back to markdown mode shows that it eats the formatting so that only a `>!` remains — I can’t even add back the image link because the reference is removed.

---

Side note: It is also tricky to add alt text in the new editor because I can’t see the image when I am typing where the alt text goes (I would have to type the alt below the image in preview mode and then switch to markdown and move it).

---

Bonus bug:

In making this post I noticed another bug (old editor): adding a link with the button messed up my codeblock, removing `[1]: example.com` reference from it.

Comment: Does adding a space before the `!` fix it?

Comment: @zcoop98 Sure, sometimes. But if the editor defaults into preview mode there is nothing left there to edit.

Comment: The fact the incorrect markdown is stripped when switching modes, is, admittedly, **_maddening_**, so I agree. That's by far the biggest flaw I see in the new editor.

Comment: I don’t believe the markdown is incorrect. The fact is that a quoted image is produced from this markdown when you’re editing in the old editor, or even in the new editor’s markdown mode.

Comment: You're right; I should've written "Markdown the new editor doesn't recognize/ like".